# Increase size of points ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datasets:

```
mydata1 <- data.frame(Class=letters[1:10], Magnitude = rnorm(10, 3, sd = 1),
                      pValue= abs(rnorm(10, 8, 5)), number= sample (10:50, 10))
mydata2 <- data.frame(Class=letters[1:10], Magnitude = rnorm(10, 2, sd = 0.5),
                      pValue= abs(rnorm(10, 3, 4)), number= sample (10:50, 10))
```

I am trying to make two graphs maintaining the same scale between them

```
ggplot(mydata1, aes(x=Magnitude, y=number, size=pValue, label=Class), guide=F) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0,16), breaks = c(0,2,6,10,16))
ggplot(mydata2, aes(x=Magnitude, y=number, size=pValue, label=Class), guide=F) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0,16), breaks = c(0,2,6,10,16))
```

My simple question is, how do I increase (proportionally) the size of the points? They are too small on the graph. The argument `max_size` is not recognized within `scale_size_continuous`.

And if I use

```
ggplot(mydata2, aes(x=Magnitude, y=number, size=pValue, label=Class), guide=F) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0,16), breaks = c(0,2,6,10,16)) +
    scale_size_area(max_size=8)
```

it overrides the `scale_size_continuous`.

Any help is appreciated as I run out of options ...

Comment: UPDATE: I think i figured it out...
`ggplot(mydata2, aes(x=Magnitude, y=number, size=pValue, label=Class), guide=F) +
    geom_point() + scale_size_area(limits=c(0,16), breaks = c(0,2,6,10,16), size=8)`

Comment: Why not use the `range` argument?

Comment: Hi Henrik, how would i implement the range argument considering that two two datasets have different ranges? I'd like to see your solution (my skills are rudimental). Thanks

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you wish to achieve. Have you looked at the [**output of the `scale_size` help text examples**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_size.html) to get a feeling how the `range` argument can be used?